# Jquery and Typescript [ts] Argument of type 'string | number | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Tags: jquery, typescript, types

I have a large existing project that is being converted to typescript and will eventually be refactored and then put into Angular. The current project has a lot of Jquery in it. I have a current @types implemented into the project.

The issue is that this line

```
if (["Priority", "PM"].indexOf($('option:selected', this).val()) >= 0) {
```

is creating an error because of type definitions. I get [TS] Argument of type 'string | number | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Because the indexOf is defined as "(method) Array.indexOf(searchElement: string, fromIndex?: number): number" and Jquery's .val is defined as "JQuery.val(): string | number | string[] (+1 overload)".

I need a way to override the .val definition, to just string so that I can get it to compile, for lines like this without overriding .val for the whole project. I have many lines that are like this in the project so I'm not able to just rewrite everyone of them yet. Eventually we will get rid of Jquery entirely. If anyone can point me to the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 12):

I finally figured out how to make it work. I was able to cast the type string to it. Since I had that exact line several places in the project I created a variable like this:

```
let optSel: string = <string>$('option:selected', this).val();

if ($(["Priority", "PM"]).index(optSel) >= 0) {
```

This allowed me to make sure that the .val type was a string which matched the indexOf requirement of Array.indexOf(searchElement: string. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: sounds like the current best way to do this is `let optSel: string = ($('option:selected', this).val() as string);`

Answer (score 3):

Your current approach is a valid solution, but that would require you to cast all occurrences of `$('option:selected').val()` to the expected type of `string`. Something you might want to consider is making use of ambient declarations in which you override/extend to the `JqueryStatic` interface in `@types/jquery`.

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    (opts: 'option:selected', ...args): {
        val: () => string;
    };
}
```

Whenever `$('option:selected', ...)` is called, the definition for this call will insists that the returned object contains a `val` method that returns a string value.

```
let value: string = $('option:selected').val();
```

If you use this throughout your project in multiple files, you can create a declaration file (*d.ts) for it, otherwise I'd suggest to just add the ambient type declaration at the top of your current file.